# send information from a web form

Tags: php, forms, smtp

I am trying to send an email through a web form but I am getting an error......
I configured my php environment on a windows server 2008 R2(64 bit) split server(2 server environment) where one server runs mysql and the other server runs php and apache(installed using xammp).  I get the following error when I run the website:

> Warning: mail() [function.mail]: Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in C:\xampp\htdocs\contact.php on line

The following is the php script:

```
if(empty($_POST) === false)
    {
        //Array to store and output errors
        $errors = array();

        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $subject = $_POST['subject'];
        $feedback = $_POST['feedback'];

        //check if the all the required fields have been completed
        if(empty($name)=== true || empty($email)=== true || empty($subject)=== true || empty($feedback) === true)
            {
                $errors[] = 'Name, email, subject and message are required';
            }
        else
            {
                //check if the email is valid
                if(filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false )
                    {
                        $errors[] = 'That\'s not a valid email address';
                    }
                //check if the name contains any numbers
                if (ctype_alpha($name)=== false)
                    {
                        $errors[] = 'Name must only contain letters';
                    }
            }

    }

    //if there are no errors then send the email
    if(empty($errors) === true)
        {
            //send email
            mail('erecruitment@saqa.co.za','$subject','$feedback','FROM:'.'$email');

            //redirect users
            header('Location: contact.php?sent');
            //exit();
        }
```

The following are from php.ini file:

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = localhost
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 25




; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
;sendmail_from = me@example.com
```

I am still getting to grips with php, it will be great if someone can help me see what I am doing wrong

Comment: try to change your SMTP host and port not use localhost you can't send mail on localhost try to it on your live server/site

Comment: I changed the SMTP host and port number on the server hosting php and apache, but  I still get the same error. Do I need to specify the server name and smtp address. i.e SMTP = 172.x.x.x/mail.boom.com ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you run sendmail server on your local machine? You can get it [here](http://www.glob.com.au/sendmail/).

For testing purposes you can use [test mail server tool](http://www.toolheap.com/test-mail-server-tool/). It will emulate sending emails.

Comment: thanks @nord_ua. I downloaded it, just need to make internet available on the server then I will feedback to you